line of code validated but not working in-game
When I do this line of code:
EquipmentLibraryItem equipmentLibraryItem = equipmentLibrary.content
    .Where(elem => elem.itemData == itemToDisable)
    .First();

It is well taken into account by Visual Studio but on Unity it writes this to me:

InvalidOperationException: Sequence contains no elements
System.Linq.Enumerable.First[TSource] (System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[T] source) (at <15efa2e8d4eb43768dbcaf9f72196952>:0)
Equipment.DisablePreviousEquipedEquipment (ItemData itemToDisable) (at Assets/Scripts/Equipment.cs:60)

I don't really have an excellent level on Unity but I'm trying to get by but I'm having a bit of trouble if someone can help me it would be great.

How, do you think, C# has to pickFirst(), when Sequence contains no elements ??

This is a runtime error and not a compilation error. Therefore, you are not getting an error in Visual Studio.
It is the .First() extension method which throws the exception, because it expects at least one element in the sequence.
You can use .FirstOrDefault() instead. This will yield null when the sequence is empty instead of throwing an exception. You will have to check whether equipmentLibraryItem is  null subsequently:
EquipmentLibraryItem equipmentLibraryItem = equipmentLibrary.content
    .Where(elem => elem.itemData == itemToDisable)
    .FirstOrDefault();
if (equipmentLibraryItem != null) {
    // proceed here
}

